# Getting 2 different local subnets to see each other

Tags: networking

This may be a question for superuser.com, given its intent, but that site isn't up yet. :)

I'm using my MacBook's Internet sharing to share its Wi-Fi connection with my Xbox 360. This works, and I can see the Internet from the Xbox, which is fine. What I'd like to do is get my Xbox to be able to see my other computers on my main network, so that I can do media sharing. I have a network that is on the 192.168.2.x subnet, and my Internet sharing on my MacBook is set up on the 192.168.20.x subnet. My MacBook obviously can see my media PC over the wireless network. How do I get across the 2 subnets so my Xbox can see my media PC?

Comment: Actually this question - put in another context - could be interesting for sysadmins.

Comment: I agree with splattne, having come across virtually the same problem in a business network.

Answer (score 6):

You could set the subnet mask on all machines to

```
  255.255.224.0
```

This way your host IP address range is 192.168.0.1 - 192.168.31.254, which includes both subnets you mention.

Comment: And to prevent network unpleasantness, make sure to do this to _everything_, including the Cable/DSL router

Comment: This seems like a viable solution...by my wireless router won't let me! It has a drop-down list of predefined subnet masks, all of which start with 255.255.255  :/

Comment: Since it is at home you could just change the subnet mask to 255.255.0.0 which should work.  Like Matt says - do it on everything.  Would be very unwise to do this in a large environment though.

Comment: I no longer have the problem described above, since I bit the bullet and bought the wireless adapter, and I also bought a new router which is more lenient on the subnet masks I can have on my LAN. Stupid WRT110.

Answer (score 1):

In going with what seems to really be your problem in your commect to Matt's answer here is the solution I use:

To connect my Xbox I got a cheap wireless bridge - you could actually do it with a cheap router too, just turn off the router stuff. Plug the Xbox into the bridge/router and hook that into your wireless network. It works like a charm for me. I used to use a WRT54G to do this but have since upgraded to Cisco small biz gear as I started using 802.1x on my wireless network.

Answer (score 1):

You might be able to do this by adding a second IP address to your media PC that's in the same subnet as the XBOX.  If that works fine for you, it's probably the least painful solution.

To do this (assuming Windows XP), go to the properties of your LAN connection, Internet Protocol (TCP/IP) properties, Advanced button, and add it there.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use some sort of gateway or router between the 2 networks, but I would recommend using only one network for all of your PCs.

Comment: There's no way to do this on the machines themselves? I know there's a ROUTE command in windows, although I'll be the first to admit I have no idea what it does.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how the XBOX "sees" the other machines, but probably via broadcast. If that is the case, you need to get an actual AP to put on the .2.x network, since your Mac is acting like a router (and routers divide broadcast domains).

The overall solution is to get the XBox on the .2.x network, however you want to accomplish that.

Comment: What I'm trying to avoid is shelling out the $100 for the xbox wireless adapter, and running 75' of ethernet cable throughout my apartment. :)

Comment: XBOX uses a non routed protocol to talk to other machines on the network.